# how objective function with "value at risk " term linearized?

Tags: probability, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

in value at risk problem , I encountered this scenario based problem :

$\min  \{c^Tx+min\{t: pr(\sum_s b^s y^s <t  )\ge 1-\alpha\}$

subject to

$Ax \le d $

$B^s x+D^s y^s \le h^s $

$x,y^s \ge0$

where " pr "is  probability. s  Is scenario.

in value at risk we usually have $ min\{t: pr(\sum_s b^s y^s <t  )\ge 1-\alpha$

I can't linearized this problem.

How can I  solve?
How to be linearized?

my try is:

suppose $min\{t: pr(\sum_s b^s y^s <t  )\ge 1-\alpha\} = T$

then we have

$\min  \{c^Tx+T\}$

subject to

$ T \ge pr(\sum_s b^s y^s <t  )\ge 1-\alpha$

$Ax \le d $

$B^s x+D^s y^s \le h^s $

$x,y^s \ge0$

then we muust linearized it, so

$\min  \{c^Tx+T$

subject to

$ pr(\sum_s b^s y^s <t  )\ge 1-\alpha$

$ pr(\sum_s b^s y^s <t  )\le T$

$Ax \le d $

$B^s x+D^s y^s \le h^s $

$x,y^s \ge0$

then according to chance constrain linearization

$\min  \{c^Tx+T\}$

subject to

$\sum_s b^s y^s <t  +M (1- \delta_1 ^s)$

$\sum_s p^s  \delta_1 ^s \ge 1- \alpha $

$ \sum_s b^s y^s <t  +M (1- \delta_2 ^s)$

$\sum_s p^s \ \delta_2 ^s\le T $

$Ax \le d $

$B^s x+D^s y^s \le h^s $

$x,y^s \ge0 $
$ \delta_1 ^s, \delta_2 ^s \in \{0,1\}$

Comment: Do you mean to enforce $\text{Pr}(b^Ty<t)\ge1-\alpha$ where $b$ is a vector-valued random variable with a finite number of realizations $b^s$ for $s=1,\dots,K$?

Comment: Do you want $t$ in place of $min\{t: pr(\sum_s b^s y^s <t  )\ge 1-\alpha\}$ in the objective function, and add a constraint $pr(\sum_s b^s y^s <t  )\ge 1-\alpha\}$? You will need to evaluate or approximate that probability in order to create a workable constraint, and that depends on your probability model. If that can be expressed as a second order cone constraint, then you should be happy you have a Second Order Cone Problem (SOCP), which is not that much harder to solve than a Linear Program, and for which there are high quality solvers readily available, so perhaps no need to linearize.

Comment: @David M. yes , b is uncertain

Comment: But has only a finite number of realization $b^s$, correct?

Comment: yes , i write something but i am not sure its tru

Comment: $ pr (\sum_s b^s y^s <t ) \le T $

  i think only this section is not true , because  this say T must be $T\in [0,1]$

Comment: @Mark L. Stone  I did it this way  and I feel it is not right,is it correct? thanks

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your formulation. Is $b^s$ itself a random variable for each $s$? Or is $b^s$ one possible value of another random variable (call is $b$)?

Comment: @David M. in problem we have random variable $ b^s , B^s,D^s, h^s$ ,$x $is The decision variable of the first stage , and $y^s$ Decision variable of the second stage . original problem to form of $c^T x+\sum_s p^s b^s y^s$ . and the value at risk form is above

Comment: So do you wish to minimize $c^\text{T}x+\mathbb{E}[b^\text{T}y]$ or $c^\text{T}x+\text{VaR}_{1-\alpha}(b^\text{T}y)$?

Comment: @David M. Honestly, I do not know what to do.
I am beginner in Value at risk , and I do not know when we want to enter value at risk in the objective function. Should we consider the $b^s y^s$ or $b y$  .  but i think i want to minimize $ c^Tx+VaR_{1−α}(b^{S}y^S)$

Comment: Value-at-risk is typically intractable (and thus definitely not LP-representable), and that is why conditional value-at-risk is used instead (and Cvar has better properties as a risk measure also).

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to answer here based on my best interpretation of what you're asking.

The problem you wish to solve is

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rl}
\min\ & c^\text{T}x + \text{VaR}_{1-\alpha}(b(\xi)^\text{T}y) \\
\text{s.t.}\ & B(\xi)x+D(\xi)y\leqslant h(\xi) \\
& x,y\geqslant 0
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where $\xi$ is a random variable with finite support (*i.e.* has a finite number $N$ of realizations, which we index $s=1,\dots,N$). An equivalent formulation on this problem is

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rl}
\min\ & c^\text{T}x + t \\
\text{s.t.}\ & t\geqslant\text{VaR}_{1-\alpha}(b(\xi)^\text{T}y) \\
& B(\xi)x+D(\xi)y\leqslant h(\xi) \\
& x,y\geqslant 0
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Now, the [definition of VaR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_at_risk#Mathematical_definition) is

$$ \text{VaR}_{1-\alpha}(b(\xi)^\text{T}y)=F_Y^{-1}(\alpha), $$

where $F_Y$ is the CDF of the random variable $b(\xi)^\text{T}y$. Since CDFs are non-decreasing by definition, the following are equivalent:

$$ t\geqslant\text{VaR}_{1-\alpha}(b(\xi)^\text{T}y)\iff F_Y(t)\geqslant\alpha\iff\text{Pr}[b(\xi)^\text{T}y\leqslant{t}]\geqslant\alpha. $$

Basically, we have reduced our problem to the following program:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rl}
\min\ & c^\text{T}x + t \\
\text{s.t.}\ & \text{Pr}[b(\xi)^\text{T}y\leqslant{t}]\geqslant\alpha \\
& B(\xi)x+D(\xi)y\leqslant h(\xi) \\
& x,y\geqslant 0
\end{array}
\end{equation}

The problem is that this formulation doesn't make much sense. If we want to solve a problem with recourse then the constraint

$$ \text{Pr}[b(\xi)^\text{T}y\leqslant{t}]\geqslant\alpha $$

doesn't make much sense, since we are choosing $y$ *after* the random variable $\xi$ is realized. On the other hand, if we are doing a true chance constraint, then we must choose $y$ before $\xi$ is realized, in which case, it's not clear what the constraint

$$ B(\xi)x+D(\xi)y\leqslant h(\xi) $$

means. Do we want to enforce this for all realizations of $\xi$? Just some? Do we want to enforce it as a chance constraint?

(It's sort of uncommon for scenario-based recourse models and chance constraints to be used in the same model).

Comment: Thanks a lot , I still did not understand ,what I thought was right or not. But thanks any way.

Comment: I think what you wrote in your question was incorrect because the expression $\text{Pr}[\sum_sb^sy^s<t]\geqslant\alpha$ isn’t meaningful, as the expression inside of $\text{Pr}[\cdot]$ isn’t a random variable.

Comment: If you write it for a scenario , everything is right

Comment: @David M. OK , thank you

Comment: $min c^T x+E_ξ Q(x,ξ)$
$s. t. Ax = b   ,x ≥ 0 $  and $Q(x,ξ) = min{q^T y | Wy = h−Tx,y ≥ 0} $, $ξ $is the vector formed by the
components of$ q^T , h^T ,$ and T , and $Eξ $denote mathematical expectation with
respect to $ξ $.

Comment: @David M.if  I want to use value at risk for "farmer example ,( scenario based) on birge book " , can i use value at risk?  as you say we cant right?